# Select only maximum value record for multiple rows

Tags: sql-server

I have one table, which having records like

```
Unit    Rate    Date-effected
-------------------------------------------
ALHA    ILS     2014-03-02 00:00:00.000
ALHA    ILS     2014-08-02 00:00:00.000
BUCK    ILS     2013-02-14 00:00:00.000
BUCK    ILS     2014-03-02 00:00:00.000
BUCK    ILS     2014-08-02 00:00:00.000
CASC    ILD     2013-02-14 00:00:00.000
CASC    ILD     2014-03-02 00:00:00.000
CASC    ILD     2014-08-02 00:00:00.000
```

now, I want only maximum date value record selection in result `table`. which is,

```
Unit    Rate    DateEffected
-------------------------------------------
ALHA    ILS     2014-08-02 00:00:00.000
BUCK    ILS     2014-08-02 00:00:00.000
CASC    ILD     2014-08-02 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Please format your data so it will be easy for us to understand. also indicate the table name and column name

Comment: Look into the MAX and GROUP BY operators, they're exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps.

```
SELECT
 Unit,
 Rate,
MAX(DateEffected) AS MaxDateEffected
FROM TableName
GROUP BY  Unit,Rate
```

Comment: If i want to use this with join query then?

Comment: I don't think you would need to take any join here.

Comment: i want to use it with other tables.

Comment: You can take join with another table as long as non-aggregated columns specified in SELECT remains same. I mean it should not have any impact on final result.

Comment: You can always put this query in a sub-query, and join it to other tables

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`ROW_NUMBER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) for this:

```
SELECT Unit, Rate, DateEffected
FROM (
  SELECT Unit, Rate, DateEffected,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Unit 
                            ORDER BY DateEffected DESC) AS rn
FROM mytable) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Comment: Why not simple group by?

Comment: This is correct (as is the other answer). Be aware, however, only one record is returned if there are two records with the max date. If this is not what is required, `DENSE_RANK()` or `RANK()` should be used.